# I can't figure out how to analyze this data

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm having an issue trying to pull a report in Crystal. Here is a sample of the data fields I need to pull. This is data for one particular incident.

```
inci_id     timestamp             transtyp  descript        unitcode
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   D   Dispatched  E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   D   Dispatched  E13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   DXY DispatchXY  E13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   D   Dispatched  R13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   DXY DispatchXY  R13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   D   Dispatched  TK10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   D   Dispatched  E10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   DXY DispatchXY  E10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   DXY DispatchXY  R10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   D   Dispatched  R10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   D   Dispatched  BC3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:57 AM   DXY DispatchXY  BC3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:58 AM   D   Dispatched  FTO3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:58 AM   DXY DispatchXY  FTO3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:58 AM   D   Dispatched  TAC1
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:13 AM   AK  {E13} STATION ACKNOWLEDGE   E13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:19 AM   AK  {E10} STATION ACKNOWLEDGE   E10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:21 AM   E   En-Route    R10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:24 AM   AK  {FTO3} STATION ACKNOWLEDG   FTO3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:30 AM   AK  {E16} STATION ACKNOWLEDGE   E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:38 AM   E   En-Route    E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:46 AM   E   En-Route    FTO3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:58 AM   AK  {BC3} STATION ACKNOWLEDGE   BC3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:10 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:12 AM   E   En-Route    E10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:14 AM   E   En-Route    E13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:18 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:19 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:22 AM   E   En-Route    TK10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:23:24 AM   E   En-Route    R13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:25:11 AM   E   En-Route    BC3
140102994   1/3/2014  10:26:51 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:27:37 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:27:39 AM   ARM Added Remarks   
140102994   1/3/2014  10:27:39 AM   IC  {E16} INCIDENT COMMAND  E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:28:12 AM   A   Arrived E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:28:41 AM   A   Arrived R13
140102994   1/3/2014  10:28:51 AM   A   Arrived R10
140102994   1/3/2014  10:29:04 AM   A   Arrived E13
```

The report I'm trying to build needs to compare the timestamps for a particular unit when Dispatched (transtype = D) and when the same unit Arrives (transtype = A), and then subtracts A from D to give the difference.  Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry guys, first time posting here. I thought the data looked correct. I will repost with legible data

Comment: Are you only interested in `D-A`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
inci_id     timestamp               transtyp  descript                    unitcode
140102994   1/3/2014  10:20:56 AM   D         Dispatched                  E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:30 AM   AK        {E16} STATION ACKNOWLEDGE   E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:22:38 AM   E         En-Route                    E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:27:39 AM   IC        {E16} INCIDENT COMMAND      E16
140102994   1/3/2014  10:28:12 AM   A         Arrived                     E16
```

I'd use a `command` with this query:

```
SELECT  d.inci_id, d.unitcode, d.timestamp dispatched, a.timestamp arrived
FROM    (
  SELECT inci_id, unitcode, timestamp
  FROM   table
  WHERE  transtyp='D'
)
-- require an 'Arrived' event; switch to LEFT OUTER JOIN if this isn't a requirement
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT inci_id, unitcode, timestamp
  FROM   table
  WHERE  transtyp='A'
) a ON d.inci_id=a.inci_id AND d.unitcode=a.unitcode
```

You will have one row for each unitcode.  You can then create a formula that gives you the difference:

```
// {@elapsed}
{command.arrived} - {command.dispatched}
```